# NATS subject subscribers limit

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

How can I limit NATS subscriptions on a specified subject?

My use case would be to distribute messages on a partitioned network so I need to limit subscription on a determined subject to exactly one.

For example the subjects example.{1,N} should have only 1 subscriber

Comment: It kind of defeats the purpose of publish/subscribe. You can limit a user to have exclusive access to a subject and then use the user only one time. You could create a JetStream and limit the MaxConsumers on the stream.
Maybe you can clarify why the subject needs to have only one subscriber so we can understand the use case a bit better.